# App crashes with "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1 " only on real device

Tags: android, variables, split, android-emulator

I was programming a function which is replacing for example 1000 for 1K and so on. I dont want to show `"00"` after the dot, so I split the variable and if the second part equals "00" it shows only the first part.

This work just as intended on the emulator running Android 10. On my real device (P4XL, Android 10) it crashes with the line shown in the title.

#### I know that this function is the reason for the crash, because when I comment it out it works on my real device as well, just without the numbers beiing displayed correctly.

*Why is it doing this?*

```
public String number_uppercase(int input){
    double input_double = (double) input;
    if (input < 1000){
        number_uppercase_cache = df.format(input_double);
        number_uppercase_ending = "";
    }
    if (input >= 1000 && input < 1000000){
        number_uppercase_cache = df.format(input_double/1000);
        number_uppercase_ending = " K";
    }
    if (input >= 1000000 && input < 1000000000){
        number_uppercase_cache = df.format(input_double/1000000);
        number_uppercase_ending = " mio";
    }
    if (input >= 1000000000){
        number_uppercase_cache = df.format(input_double/1000000000);
        number_uppercase_ending = " mrd";
    }

    number_uppercase_split_part_1 = number_uppercase_cache.split("\\.")[0];
    number_uppercase_split_part_2 = number_uppercase_cache.split("\\.")[1];

    if(number_uppercase_split_part_2.equals("00")){
        number_uppercase_output = number_uppercase_split_part_1 + number_uppercase_ending;
    } else {
        number_uppercase_output = number_uppercase_split_part_1 + "." + number_uppercase_split_part_2 + number_uppercase_ending;
    }
    return number_uppercase_output;
}
```

Comment: [And why you think that decimal place separator is always dot?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator)

Comment: It was all the time, I dont see a reason for it to turn into a comma.

Comment: [Where is dot here?](https://ideone.com/WgkAj2) the error is obvious - split returns one element array

Comment: Why doesnt it return two elements? [0] before dot and [1] after dot.. And why does this error only occur on a real device and not in the emulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give a try to below function which will serve your purpose

```
private String formatNumber(long _number) {
    if (_number< 1000) 
        return "" + _number ;
    else
    int exp = (int) (Math.log(_number) / Math.log(1000));
    return String.format("%.1f %c", _number/ Math.pow(1000, exp), "kMGTPE".charAt(exp-1));
}
```

Comment: Just one more question, is there a way to remove the 0 after the dot if its not needed?